# Google spreadsheet add row on first edit of a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Ok... I am new to google docs, but have a limited knowledge of excel spreadsheets.

I have a very simple spreadsheet that accepts a date as the first value, followed by various financial data, some of which is entered manually and some auto-calculated based on that input.

The sheet also contains a summery row, which is positioned 2 rows below the last data row (just to make it look good).

Now.. what I would like to do, is when a user enters a date in one of the 2 blank rows below the last entry, I would like a script to first check if that date is valid (and not just a space or something), and to make sure its the first time that cell has been updated, and assuming both are true, create a new row directly below it and fill in the proper formulas to make the auto-generated stuff work in it like they do in the ones created by hand.

I know this is possible with a custom function, but just can't seem to get it to work.

Any kick in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this code below.

function onEdit(e)

{

```
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

   var row = e.range.getRow();

   var column = e.range.getColumn();

   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

   if(column == 1 && row == (lastRow-2) ){sheet.insertRowAfter(row);}
```

}

It works fine other than date validation step.You can try adding some data validation within the sheet by adding in Data-> Validation or using [DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok, let me play with that... that gives me a lot more to look at then I had... I should be able to work with that. Thanks!